# Scale down image until one side reaches goal dimension

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rmagick, carrierwave

How do you scale down an image until one side reaches it's goal dimension with Carrierwave and rmagick?

Example:

Goal dimensions: 600x400

Picture being uploaded: 700x450

I want this image to be scaled down until the height reaches 400 pixels keeping the original aspect ratio.

That would result in a image with the following dimensions: 622x400

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might take a look at `resize_to_limit`. From the carrierwave docs:

> Resize the image to fit within the specified dimensions while retaining the original aspect ratio. Will only resize the image if it is larger than the specified dimensions. The resulting image may be shorter or narrower than specified in the smaller dimension but will not be larger than the specified values.

So you could do something like this in your uploader:

```
process :resize_to_fill => [600, 400]
```

If you don't mind to crop the image, you could go for `resize_to_fit` instead, and use the gravity value that you desire:

> From the RMagick documentation: “Resize the image to fit within the specified dimensions while retaining the original aspect ratio. The image may be shorter or narrower than specified in the smaller dimension but will not be larger than the specified values.“

**Edit:**
You can [read the documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/0.5.8/CarrierWave/RMagick) for these processors for more options on resizing

For a `resize_to_min` implementation that would only enforce minimum dimensions for your width and height, you can take `resize_to_limit` as base and just modify the geometry setting to `MinimumGeometry` to create a custom processor:

```
  process :resize_to_min => [600, 400]

  def resize_to_min(width, height)
    manipulate! do |img|
      geometry = Magick::Geometry.new(width, height, 0, 0, Magick::MinimumGeometry)
      new_img = img.change_geometry(geometry) do |new_width, new_height|
        img.resize(new_width, new_height)
      end
      destroy_image(img)
      new_img = yield(new_img) if block_given?
      new_img
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks I've tested all the built in processes but I want to do something like; “Resize the image to fit within the specified dimensions while retaining the original aspect ratio. The image may be taller or broader than specified in the bigger dimension but will not be smaller than the specified values.“ So maybe something like :resize_to_fit_width_or_height but not sure how I would implement it.

Comment: I think that's exactly what `resize_to_limit` does.

Comment: Ah sorry, now I see the difference. I thought that processor was also included.

Comment: I think your custom processor could take `resize_to_limit` as base and just change the geometry setting from `GreaterGeometry` to `MinimumGeometry`. I'll update the post with the method.

Answer (score 1):

Use algebra: http://www.algebrahelp.com/lessons/proportionbasics/pg2.htm

Since 622px > 600px, you need to set the width to 600px and calculate the correct height which maintains aspect ratio:

```
700/450 = 600/x
(700/450)*x = 600
x = 600/(700/450)
x ~= 386
```

Your desired size is: 600px x 386px

This will fit within the goal dimensions, maximizing size, while maintaining aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the sides to never be smaller than 600 or 400 depending on the aspect ratio. Bigger is OK though but I want one side to always reach it's goal width/height. So my desired size is 622x400, this is so I can present a scaled down version of the image for the user to crop to 600x400.